# I'm trying to convert a functional componet into a class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, react-tsx

I have a table of data which adds a new column for each new object within an array.  The functional component works just fine, but I want to practice over class components so I started to play around with some small components that I made and convert them to class components.

```
import someData from ...

export default function PageTable(): JSX.Element {

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(someData);

    function addNewRowsWithRandomData() {
        let randomObject = tableData[Math.floor(Math.random() * tableData.length)];
        setTableData((prevData): any => {
            let newDataArray = [...prevData, randomObject];
            return newDataArray;
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="card">
                    <div className='card data-table' style={{ height: 'calc(80vh - 25vh)' }}>
                        <DataTable value={tableData} scrollable scrollHeight="flex" responsiveLayout="scroll" paginator
                            paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
                            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}" rows={10} rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50]}
                            resizableColumns columnResizeMode="fit" showGridlines>
                            <Column field="id" header="ID" sortable></Column>
                            <Column field="employeeStatus" header="Status" sortable></Column>
                            <Column field="lastName" header="Last Name" filter filterPlaceholder="Search by name" style={{ minWidth: '12rem' }}></Column>
                            <Column field="firstName" header="First Name" filter filterPlaceholder="Search by name" style={{ minWidth: '12rem' }}></Column>
                            <Column field="salutation" header="Honorifics"></Column>
                        </DataTable>
                        <Button label="Add Data" onClick={addNewRowsWithRandomData} />
                    </div>
```

Here is my approach for the class component. I tried different solutions including lifecycle methods but none worked. When I press the Add Data button nothing happens.

```
export default class ClassPageTable extends Component<{}, unknown> {
    state = {
        data: someData
    }

    addNewRowsWithRandomData = () => {
        let randomObject = someData[Math.floor(Math.random() * someData.length)];
        this.setState((prevData: any): any => {
            [...prevData.data, randomObject];

        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className='card data-table' style={{ height: 'calc(80vh - 25vh)' }}>
                        <DataTable value={this.state.data} scrollable scrollHeight="flex" responsiveLayout="scroll" paginator
                            paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
                            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}" rows={10} rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50]}
                            resizableColumns columnResizeMode="fit" showGridlines>
                            <Column field="id" header="ID" sortable></Column>
                            <Column field="employeeStatus" header="Status" sortable></Column>
                            <Column field="lastName" header="Last Name" filter filterPlaceholder="Search by name" style={{ minWidth: '12rem' }}></Column>
                            <Column field="firstName" header="First Name" filter filterPlaceholder="Search by name" style={{ minWidth: '12rem' }}></Column>
                            <Column field="salutation" header="Honorifics"></Column>
                        </DataTable>
                        <Button label="Add Data" onClick={this.addNewRowsWithRandomData} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: You are not adding your random object to the data in state. Try this `this.setState({data:[...prevData.data, randomObject]})`.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I got stuck at something so obvious.

Comment: the state works differently on class component than on functional component. So coming from FC background you might assume similar behaviour, but actually it works differently.